# Error: "The specified data type is unavailable" When pasting Shapes as PNG format in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, type-conversion, powerpoint

I need to write a macro to convert all grouped diagrams (shapes, arrows and text) in a PPT presentation to PNGs.  (I am converting the PPTs using some eLearning software and the diagrams end up corrupt; and I need them to be PNGs because enhanced metafiles also present issues).

I've been using some slightly modified code from a macro that converts Pictures (enhanced meta files) to PNGs.  All I did was change msoPicture to msoGroup:

```
Sub ConvertAllPicsToPNG()
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape

    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
            ' modify the following depending on what you want to
            ' convert
            Select Case oSh.Type
                Case msoGroup
                    ConvertPicToPNG oSh
                Case Else

            End Select
        Next
    Next

End Sub

Sub ConvertPicToPNG(ByRef oSh As Shape)
    Dim oNewSh As Shape
    Dim oSl As Slide

    Set oSl = oSh.Parent
    oSh.Copy
    Set oNewSh = oSl.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPastePNG)(1)

    With oNewSh
        .Left = oSh.Left
        .Top = oSh.Top
        Do
            .ZOrder (msoSendBackward)
        Loop Until .ZOrderPosition = .ZOrderPosition
    End With

    oSh.Delete

End Sub
```

I get the error "Shapes (unknown member)" on the line

```
Set oNewSh = oSl.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPastePNG)(1)
```

I suspect I'm having problems with VBA's Object Reference Model, as research has told me of GroupItems and GroupShapes, but I can't fathom it.

Comment: What version of PowerPoint are you using? I copy your code exactly in PPT 2010 and it works on a simple group of shapes (connector, rectangle, and a few other things).

Comment: Hi David,

PPT 2013.

The full error message:

Run time error '-#####'
Shapes (unknown member): Invalid request.  The specified data type is unavailable.

Thanks for your help.

Joe

Comment: Any chance you can upload an example presentation (with just one slide and some grouped shapes) to Google Docs or Dropbox?  I can't test in 2013 but wonder if I can replicate the problem with your slide.

Comment: Well, I've done just that and ran the code on one slide and it works...

So the problem must be with the other slides.  I've narrowed it down. 

I've created a doc with 2 slides: slide 1 is the offending slide, because if you delete it the code works for slide 2. [link]https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1fY-x16unj-14R3HS3aF8SD4luJZ_pZnItabIBC4JVHg/edit?usp=sharing[/link]

Comment: OK I get a similar error on slide "Shapes (unknown member) : Invalid request.  Clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted here."  Let me tinker with it for a few, I think I have an idea.

Comment: I found out something and it's weird.  If you zoom way out of the offending slide and CTRL-A/select all, you'll see there's a long mischievous text box above it (i.e. off the slide).  If I remove that, it works ... the thing is, there are loads of such offending slides in my presentations...

Comment: I did notice that but assumed it was needed for some reason. I think I will have a solution that can address that so you don't need to bother with manually removing shapes that cause this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get this error in PPT 2010: "Shapes (unknown member) : Invalid request.  Clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted here."

We both notice there is "Shape 125" when you zoom out or use the Selection Pane:

[image]

After a lot of trial and error (I thought the nesting might be a problem, and tried to un-nest them -- successfully, but the error still happened) I noticed that each of them had a height of `0`.  If I changed that to any positive value, success!

So here is the fix -- call a new function to make sure shapes have height > 0:

```
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        ' modify the following depending on what you want to
        ' convert
        Select Case oSh.Type
            Case msoGroup
                'Ensure each grouped shape has h/w of at least "1"
                FixShape oSh
                ConvertPicToPNG oSh
            Case Else
```

Here is the function:

```
Function FixShape(ByRef oSh As Shape)

Dim s As Shape
'## Iterate the GroupItems collection and ensure minimum height/width
'   for converion to png/jpg/etc.
For Each s In oSh.GroupItems
    If s.Height = 0 Then s.Height = 1
    If s.Width = 0 Then s.Width = 1
    'Recursive
    If s.Type = msoGroup Then
        Set s = FixShape(s)
    End If
Next

Set FixShape = oSh

End Function
```

Here is the final output which converts the shapes to PNG:

[image]

**Root Cause of this Error**

It seems you are not able to paste shapes with height/width of 0, as PNG format (although you can paste them as Shapes).  This seems to be an intentional limitation, but unfortunately the error message is ambiguous.

**Solution to this Error**

Ensure that shapes have minimum dimensions of 1x1 before trying to paste as an image format (PNG, JPG, etc.)

While you were able to resolve the problem by deleting the offending shape, this should help you so that you don't have to search for those off-pane shapes or try to troubleshoot this again in the future.

Comment: David, you LEGEND!  Thank you so much.  This will save me so much time!

Comment: Brilliant!  This problem appears fairly frequently.  Great work in nailing the cause down, David.  Thanks!