# Macro to reduce image sizes in a ppt that worked in ppt 2007 but not in ppt 2013

Tags: size, powerpoint, shapes, reduce

I've a macro that I used with some ppt's in office 2007 to reduce the size of some links within the ppt to an excel file. Recently I've installed the Office 2013 and the macro crashed with the following error:

> Shape.select: invalid request. To select a shape, its view must be active

Here is the code:

```
Sub reduce()
 For Each curr_slide In ActivePresentation.Slides
     curr_slide.Select
       For Each oSh In curr_slide.Shapes
           If oSh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
            Set oSh = curr_slide.Shapes(3)

             With oSh
                   '.LinkFormat.BreakLink

                   .Select
                   .LockAspectRatio = False
                   .Height = 14 * 28.33
                   .Width = 33.5 * 28.33
                   .Cut
                   Set oSh = curr_slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPastePNG)
                   .Height = 10 * 28.33
                   .Width = 23 * 28.33
                   .Left = 1.2 * 28.33
                   .Top = 1.85 * 28.33
                   .ZOrder (msoSendToBack)
               End With
           End If
       Next oSh
   Next curr_slide
End Sub
```

I believe now, I've to activate each shape in every slide but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may simply be that you're in a view that doesn't permit selecting slides, so ... don't select slides.  There's no need to:

```
Sub reduce()
 For Each curr_slide In ActivePresentation.Slides
     ' you don't need to select the slide to work with it
     'curr_slide.Select
       For Each oSh In curr_slide.Shapes
           If oSh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then

            ' Is there something magical about the third shape?
            ' And you're messing up your loop by setting
            ' oSh to a different shape here. 
            'Set oSh = curr_slide.Shapes(3)
            ' Instead, do this:
             With curr_slide.Shapes(3)
                   '.LinkFormat.BreakLink

                   .Select
                   .LockAspectRatio = False
                   .Height = 14 * 28.33
                   .Width = 33.5 * 28.33
                   .Cut

                   ' And again, setting oSh to a different
                   ' value within the loop is bad practice:
                   Dim PastedShape as Shape
                   Set oPastedShape = curr_slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPastePNG)
                   ' and this, if you want the following code
                   ' to affect the pasted shape:
                   With oPastedShape
                   .Height = 10 * 28.33
                   .Width = 23 * 28.33
                   .Left = 1.2 * 28.33
                   .Top = 1.85 * 28.33
                   .ZOrder (msoSendToBack)
                   End with

               End With
           End If
       Next oSh
   Next curr_slide
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried your approach but now I've the following error: "Shape.select: invalid request. To select a shape, its view must be active ". How do I activate the shape in each slide?

Comment: I've also comented out the ".select" within the loop but it gave me a error related to the data type: "Shapes.PasteSpecial: Invalid request. The specified data type is unavailable."

Comment: Sorry, I missed the second .Select.  You're correct, it should be removed. And change Dim PastedShape to Dim oPastedShape.  Does that sort things?

Comment: "Shapes.PasteSpecial: Invalid Request. The specified data type is unavailable." =\

Comment: See this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24675562/error-the-specified-data-type-is-unavailable-when-pasting-shapes-as-png-forma  and also change the offending line to  Set oPastedShape = curr_slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPastePNG)(1)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem, basically by defining my datatype with the associated ID number instead of indicating the traditional "ppPasteXPTO". I've also used the number of the Bitmap format file instead of the PNG since it allows me to reduce the size of the ppt but it's not so heavy in the image compression like the PNG is. Here is the final code:

```
Sub reduce()

Dim shp As Shape
Dim sld As Slide

'Loop Through Each Slide in ActivePresentation
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
     If shp.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
        shp.Cut
        Dim oShp As ShapeRange
        Set oShp = sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=1)
     End If
    Next shp
  Next sld
End Sub
```